# Possible function/variable hoisting issue

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, local-storage

Originally you press a button, prompts appear asking for entries, the entries get placed into the Type "Wall", and then the type gets "pushed" into the array "walls".  After that the function `wallTable()` is called which arranges the array `walls` into a HTML5 table on the front end. (This all worked fine)

Heres the `wallTable()` function:

```
function wallTable(){
    var tableDiv = document.getElementById("wallTable"),
        table = "<table border='1'>" +
            "<thread><th>Room</th><th>Surface</th><th>Material</th><th>Width</th><th>Height</th><th>Surface Area</th></thread>";
    for(var i = 0, j = walls.length; i<j; i++){
        var wallTable = walls[i];
        console.log("Check 2");
        table += wallTable.tableRow();  //Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function.  wallTable       <------------?????????????????????????
        console.log("Check 3");
    }
    table += "</table>";
    tableDiv.innerHTML = table;
}
```

This program needs to store data after it's closed and bring it back and place it in the table again when reopened, I used `localStoreage()` in conjunction with `JSON.stringify` to store the `walls` array and `JSON.parse` to get it back again.  From what I can tell form putting in some `console.logs()` is this works fine but when it tries to place the array into the table on loading it runs into an error.

```
if(localStorage.getItem("wallArray")!== null){
    walls = JSON.parse(localStorage["wallArray"]);
    console.log("Check 1");
    wallTable(walls);   //(anonymous function)      <--------------------?????????????????????????????
}
//Table functions
function wallTable(){
    var tableDiv = document.getElementById("wallTable"),
        table = "<table border='1'>" +
            "<thread><th>Room</th><th>Surface</th><th>Material</th><th>Width</th><th>Height</th><th>Surface Area</th></thread>";
    for(var i = 0, j = walls.length; i<j; i++){
        var wallTable = walls[i];
        console.log("Check 2");
        table += wallTable.tableRow();  //Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function.  wallTable       <------------?????????????????????????
        console.log("Check 3");
    }
    table += "</table>";
    tableDiv.innerHTML = table;
}
```

If there's nothing in the `localStorage("wallArray")` the program runs fine even after entering things.  It's only when you open the program with something in `localStorage("wallArray")` that the error is thrown.

Comment: When you pass a JavaScript object to `JSON.stringify()`, you lose all the original "personalities" of the objects; all you get is a JSON string with the property values. The subsequent call to `JSON.parse()` gives you back plain objects. Your original objects with their `.tableRow()` function will not be re-created.

Comment: Could you suggest a way of storing the information without this happening?

Comment: The [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) mechanism allows you to have some control over how objects are restored. Depending on the nature of the data you've serialized, you may be able to use that to re-create your objects with your classes. Both local storage and cookies restrict what you can save to plain strings, so without involving server-side storage there aren't other options.

Comment: You're using the same variable name in different context making everything messy. Also, why are you passing a parameter to `wallTable()` when it accepts no parameters?

Comment: Yeah thats in there because I was just throwing things at it like "PLEASE WORK!"

Answer (score 0):

You are calling wallTable() with one parameter (walls) whereas your declaration takes none...
First of all, try to declare it like that :

```
function wallTable(walls){...}
```

or if you wish to keep taking no argument, call wallTable() without any and make sure walls is properly accessible, in wallTable() scope. I assume you already declared it globally somewhere.

Comment: Yeah thats in there because I was just throwing things at it like "PLEASE WORK, WHY WON'T YOU WORK?" But now I know why thanks to Pointy

Comment: Besides, I saw your "check 1", "check 2" console.logs... This way to step into your programs is not optimal. Use console.log to directly check walls JSON parsed contents (console.log(walls)) and try to use a debugger such as FireFox's, set breakpoints where you want to halt and check any values, objects structures, arrays contents inside your DOM trees.